# How to load a properties file in java without calling laod method separately

Tags: java

How to load a properties file in java without calling laod method separately
i want to load the file while instantiation of the properties object itself. 
like i have pasted below but i am not able to succeed in it.

```
class test{
Properties configFile = new Properties(load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
}
```

Comment: Programming does not work by throwing together random statements, in case you have any confusion.  Why the interest in doing it in a 'single line'?  What is the supposed advantage?

Comment: I'm guessing instancing it completely (loading it as well) in a field instead of doing it in a constructor or similar. Depending on the circumstances I guess it could be OK, for example for tests, simple programs etc.

Comment: actually i want to initialize outside the methods i mean where the variables are declared i don want to get into the method and do it.. may be i am wrong... i just wanna know is it possible to do it?

Comment: Given a read throws exceptions, it cannot be declared as a single line statement outside a method. @Pulsar: Tip for the future.  When I ask questions like that, I need an answer from the OP, rather than guesses from helpful passers-by.  OTOH thanks for trying.  :)

Comment: Well I added the comment after I had replied with an answer below. I should probably have phrased the comment as "Possible yes... see my answer below"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a separate method to do that - potentially in a helper class you can use elsewhere:

```
public class PropertiesHelper {
    public static Properties loadFromFile(String file) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            properties.load(stream);
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Note that due to the possibility of an `IOException`, you'll still need to be careful where you call this from. If you want to use it in an instance initializer, you'll need to declare that all of your constructors can throw `IOException`.

Comment: i copied this method and pasted inside my class and called the method as       `Properties config=loadFromFile("config.properties");` but its showing the error     `unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

Comment: (Basically, you need to make sure that all constructors declare that they throw IOException - which means if you want a parameterless constructor, you'll have to declare it yourself.)

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of this:

```
class Test {
    Properties configFile = new Properties() {{ load(new FileInputStream("config.properties")); }};
}
```

You are actually sub classing Properties here and using its initialization section. 
load(..) might throw an Exception if so you would need to add a `try { ... } catch () {}`

Comment: Usually not, as then you will have no error handling (no fall back, no recovery, possibly no error message etc). Can also sometimes be a bit hard to read and might get serialization warnings in your code (when sub classing a Serializable class making it less readable trying to fix that as well etc). You are doing I/O, which is often error pron. But if it's for a unit test or small test program etc etc it could arguable be OK of course.

Comment: Meant to mention it before, but `Class test{` should be `class Test{` taking into account both Java keywords and common Java nomenclature.

Comment: Thanks, fixed, I just copied it from the question and concentrated on the important part.

Comment: when i use this i m getting the error `The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long`

Comment: Not an error just a warning. But I tried to warn you about this :) Serialization warnings, so you will have to add something like this: `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` after the first curly bracket. Getting less readable...

Comment: i tried this `public class JavaApplication1 {
 final private static String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
 static final Properties configFile = new Properties() {

        {
            try {
                configFile.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
private static String DIR = osName.equals("Linux") ? configFile.getProperty("tempDirForLinux") : configFile.getProperty("tempDirForWindows");
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(DIR);
}
}` but its giving me output as `null`

Comment: Remove the `configFile.` part in `configFile.load(...)` Should only be `load(...` (you are inside that class). Works for me then. Note you should probably not use equals with the os.name property. The string could contain more than that. For example on Windows 7 it will be "Windows 7" so matching against "Windows" wouldn't work for example. Use something like `osName.toLowerCase().contains("linux")` instead.