# properties file is returning null

Tags: java

i am trying to read values from properties file and
when i tried to run this program
its giving the output as
      `null`

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
public class JavaApplication1 {
final private static String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
static final Properties configFile = new Properties() {

    {
        try {
            configFile.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
};
private static String DIR = osName.equals("Linux") ? configFile.getProperty("tempDirForLinux") : configFile.getProperty("tempDirForWindows");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(DIR);
}
}
```

Comment: Does your program load the properties correctly? Do you have the correct property in your properties?

Comment: Just as the guy in the answer to your previous question said, this is a very fragile technique you are using. For starters, at least `printStackTrace` in that catch block.

Comment: post your properties file and its location

Comment: yes my property file contains `tempDirForLinux = /tmp
tempDirForWindows = c:/temp
`

Comment: @JigarJoshi it is in the same location where this java file is...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik wat can i do to make it better?

Comment: What do get for `System.getProperty("user.dir")` ? is it where your file is ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade i get `/home/sarsarahman/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication1`

Comment: Well, did you take my advice above? Did you get an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that is a bit odd in your example is where you create an anonymous Properties class and then load the properties into that same class in an initialization statement.  I'm not sure how that is meant to work (and I'm guessing doesn't)

This is probably what you want rather

```
public class JavaApplication1 {
    final private static String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    static final Properties configFile = new Properties();

    static {
        try {
            configFile.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    private static String DIR = osName.equals("Linux") ? configFile.getProperty("tempDirForLinux") : configFile.getProperty("tempDirForWindows");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(DIR);
    }
}
```

Comment: He got it from [his previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10269151/1103872). Didn't accept it, though (shame on you, S.A.Rahman!). Anyway, it's legal and it works when there's no exception

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thank you now i got what i needed. i am really sorry for my poor english which failed to explain you what i actually needed. thank you for your advise and kind comments.

Comment: I put the above question code into my IDE and it didn't work for me or give an exception which was a bit odd.  But the code posted in the other question by MarkoTopolnik  looks like it should work too.